# Looking for interesting topic from neural networks area

Tags: neural-network

I'm preparing to give a talk about some topic I choose from artificial intelligence area (neural networks). I'm looking for something interesting, used in a real life and preferably not too complicated (the simpler it is, the easier it is for students to understand and the more interested they will be). I thought that it's a good place to look for advice ;)

Comment: What type of neural nets - is this specific to certain types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code [applying neural networks to text recognition](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simple_ocr.aspx).

I think the concept of text recognition is interesting and understandable.

Comment: this is good though i would prefer something from the scratch

Answer (score 2):

Toby Segaran's interesting book "[Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325)" contains a simple neural net example for learning search results relevancy. He offers the code from the book free on [his site](http://blog.kiwitobes.com/?p=44).

The neural net is in chapter4 code. Not sure if you could figure out the code without the text - if you don't mind spending a little money, the book certainly wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Learn your neural net the sine wave. It's simple. You only need 4 neurons. And the weights will clearly show how it's working. It was the example that made it click for me.

Comment: Can you recommend a link to an article or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The "Real life applications" [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Real_life_applications) of the (english) Wikipedia article about "Artificial neural networks" lists some (quite general) applications of neural networks.